# Matlab GUI - Axes callback for mouseclick

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am programming a GUI with matlab and somehow I have problems with the callbackfunction of a mouseclick on an axes. I found some similar topics but the solutions given there won't solve my problem.

The important parts of my code look like this (first normal try with the ButtonDownFcn of the Axes, this works aslong as I dont plot anything):

```
function Axes_1_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

disp('axis callback');
```

(second try in which I wanted to turn HitTest off, this one doesn't work at all)

```
 axes(handles.Axes_1); 
 h=plot(x,y);
 set(h,'HitTest','off');
 set(gcf,'WindowButtonDownFcn','disp(''axis callback'')')
 set(h,'ButtonDownFcn','disp(''axis callback'')')
```

Since I turned HitTest off I thought the click should work even with a plot on the axes but it doesn't. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Klaus

Update1: @matlabgui
I tried to change NextPlot to add like in your example but it still doesn't work. I think at this point I'm not familiar enough with MATLAB/GUI to understand your suggestion properly.

I hope this is not too much too ask for, but if I just created a ButtonDownFcn (empty) for the Axes itself and plot a graph like in the following code. What would I have to add to the code to display "Single click on axis" in my command window after I clicked on the axis in which the graph is displayed (no matter if I click on the empty space in the plot or the line itself)? I think it is easiest to have a short example which works in my code and then analyse this step by step.

Code for plotting:

```
axes(handles.Axes_1); 
plot(x,y);
```

empty bdfcn:

```
function Axes_1_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

Comment: I think you are supposed to do something like `set(hFig,'WindowButtonDownFcn',@myCallback)`. In other words, you assign a function handle to the `WindowButtonDownFcn`. Have you tried that? In addition to that, if possible, try to save every figure handle as a variable. I have seen code which gets real issues due to `gcf` in 2014b and later.

Comment: Thats what I'm actually doing (creating a function as callback). But since even the "disp" doesn't work I thought it would be better to simplify the problem. What do you mean by "every figure handle"? Something like ax1= axes(handles.Axes_1);  ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: By saving fig handle -> I think @patrick means dont use `gcf`, `gca` etc.....  (which is a good idea in all versions of Matlab...

Comment: @klaus You should assign a vector `figs` or a set of variables `fig1,fig2 ...` with figure handles (eg. `fig1=figure(1);`). `gcf` gets the current figure, but if you have moved the mouse during execution, then current figure may not be the figure you want, I have not got any troubles with `gca` since axises are less susceptible to interaction. `gca(hFig)` normally leads to right axis. Regarding the callback function, I mean that you use an incorrect syntax in the example. As can be seen in the answer you must have something like `set(gcf,'WindowButtonDownFcn',@(foo,bar)disp('axis callback'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line cant work because `HitTest` is off for the plot handle `h`

```
set(h,'ButtonDownFcn','disp(''axis callback'')')
```

You need to hold your axes (or change the `NextPlot` property to be `'add'`- otherwise when you create a new plot - the `ButtonDownFcn` callback of your axes will be cleared.

See examples below:

```
%% This is what you have to start with
f = figure; axes ( 'parent', f, 'ButtonDownFcn', @(a,b)disp ( 'button down on axes' ) )

%% This doesn't work -> as the plot command is clearing the axes which also clears the ButtonDownFcn
f = figure; axes ( 'parent', f, 'ButtonDownFcn', @(a,b)disp ( 'button down on axes' ) ); plot ( [1:10], [1:10] );

%% The Callback is retained by changing the axes NextPlot property
f = figure; axes ( 'parent', f, 'NextPlot', 'add', 'ButtonDownFcn', @(a,b)disp ( 'button down on axes' ) ); plot ( [1:10], [1:10] );

%% This also works by using hold on.
f = figure; axes ( 'parent', f, 'ButtonDownFcn', @(a,b)disp ( 'button down on axes' ) ); hold on; plot ( [1:10], [1:10] );
```

**Update 1**

Change your code to the following (untested code):

```
set ( handles.Axes_1, 'NextPlot', 'add' );
plot(handles.Axes_1, x,y);

% If you don't have the buttondownfcn set you add it by:
set ( handles.Axes_1, 'ButtonDownFcn', {@Axes_1_ButtonDownFcn ( handles )} );
```

Comment: I updated my main post. Thank you very for investing so much time to help me!